# Custom Edittext using onDraw and cursor position mismatch?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am making an custom Edittext . Here is the code :-

```
package com.wysiwyg.main;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LineEditText extends EditText {
    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;

    // we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
    public LineEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE); //SET YOUR OWN COLOR HERE
        setMinLines(15);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int height = getHeight();
        int line_height = getLineHeight();

        int count = height / line_height;
        if(getLineCount() > count){
            count = getLineCount();
        }
        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
            baseline += getLineHeight()+10;//next line
        }

        // Finishes up by calling the parent method
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Now this line `baseline += getLineHeight()+10;//next line` , draws the next line at a specific space above the line. Now the cursor position does not move with respect to the line. If i press enter, then the cursor first comes above the line ,then i press enter, it comes in between the line.

I hope you are getting my meaning.

Comment: what you want to achieve? Do you want to set space between lines?

Comment: I can achieve space between lines. The issue is that after achieving space, the cursor position does not come above the line. It comes in between the line

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {


    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context mContext) {
        setLineSpacing(2, 1); // You can set here as your requirement
    }


}
```